# Steps to a successful Magento Payment Bridge Installation

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-methods

I am trying to setup our new Magento EE v1.12 installation and because of our credit card processing requirements we have decided to use Authorize.net with Magento Payment Bridge. My biggest problem is that the documentation on Payment Bridge is not very clear on how to setup the software. Does anyone have clear step by step instructions on how to setup the Payment Bridge. Also, in the documentation they say that the Payment Bridge software should be installed on a separate server from the Mysql database. Is this a requirement or a recommendation? If we choose to install the software on the same server as the database, how will this affect our PCI compliance? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The seperation of database is necessary for PCI DSS compliant. Last month, a local PCI DSS agent checked in our environment. They suggested us this procedure is because of the compliance! PS : I don't know how many transaction you made over payment service but in our country, if your payment transaction over 2 million in a month, every service that interact with payment provider must complain PCI DSS.

Answer (score 4):

I am no PCI-DSS expert, but reading this:

> It is important to note that while Magento Secure Payment Bridge is a
>   PA-DSS compliant application, it must be implemented in a PCI DSS
>   compliant environment.

(ref : http://www.magentocommerce.com/company/pci-compliance) tells me that Payment Bridge in itself will not make you PCI-DSS compliant.

Your server (thus the server hosting your mysql server) should be certified. If it is, I don't see that payment bridge will make / break your compliance, as that will meet the stated requirement.

Happy to remove this answer if I am wrong.

This thread : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/199775/ is also of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am going to go with the one server setup and see if that passed the PCI audit. What I need now is better documentation for the installation and setup.